# Count total directories and files in all sub directories unix

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, grep, ls

I am trying to get a count of the subdirectories and all the files total in all the subdirectories within a directory in Unix.  I tried this:

```
ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l
```

but that just gives me the total subdirectories, not the total files.  How would I modify this or is there a way to find out both numbers from one command? Or should I split this into two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because files may contain newlines or spaces or the like, the best method is to use `find` but instead of having it print the names of the files have it print a `.` or similar for every file found.  That solution would look like

```
find . -type d -or -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
```

which will search starting in the current directory for any `-type d` or `-type f` which is directory or file.  For each it'll print `.` and then we count the number of characters printed.